# unable to execute: Too many levels of symbolic links

Tags: linux, bash, symbolic-link, sh

By mistake, I executed these commands :

```
sudo ln -sf bash /bin/sh 
sudo ln -sf bash /bin/bash
```

When I rebooted the Linux server in recovery mode I got this message:

```
init : Failed to spawn friendly-recovry pre-start process: unable to execute: Too many levels of symbolic links
```

And Linux doesn't run.

any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3):

I think you somehow ended up with

```
sh -> bash
bash -> bash
```

When the system is first trying to run a shell, it will go into a loop resolving `bash`, 
which is, according to the symlink,
the same as `bash`, which is the same as `bash`, which is the same as `bash`, which is the same as `bash`... until memory allowed for this runs out.

---

To fix the problem, we need to know what `/bin/sh` was before, normally it points to `bash` or to `dash`. Which Linux distribution do you use?

There are other shells installed normally, like `dash`, or `zsh`, but as the system looks for `sh` when starting, I see no way to make use of these without external help.

I think you will need to boot a live system from a CD, or connect the harddisk to another computer;
And from there, mount the root disk, and fix the link.
If the shell was really deleted by the "force" in `ls -sf`, you need to get the shell binary from somewhere.

Could also work to link `/bin/sh` to a similar shell, not the one it was pointing to - (but that seems to be what you were doing last.)

---

The

```
sudo ln -sf bash /bin/bash
```

could have deleted `/bin/bash` - but when I try something similar, I get an error:

```
ln: bash and /bin/bash are the same file
```

Are you sure about the commands? In which directory did you run them?